# SQL Pivot Table Dynamic causes error "The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements."

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I'm new to MS SQL Server PIVOT function and so far not so good I've no idea what I'm doing wrong...
I've had a look at many other examples but everyone seem to have different requirements.
I've a Vehicle and each Vehicle has different prices e.g. Nett Cost, Normal Selling, Net Selling & Special. I would like to pivot so that all prices are in the same row instead of multiple rows for each price.
Here's my try which is failing with the error "The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements."

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(v.[Id]) 
                    FROM [Vehicle] v
                    INNER JOIN [VehiclePrice] vp ON vp.[VehicleId]=v.[Id]
                    INNER JOIN [VehiclePriceLevel] vpl ON vpl.Id=vp.VehiclePriceLevelId
                    GROUP BY 
                        v.[Id],v.[Category],v.[Status],v.[Publication],v.[VIN], v.[EngineNumber],v.MMCode,
                        v.[Year],v.Kilometers,v.Fuel,v.Transmission,v.Colour,v.PrimaryColour,v.BodyType,v.[IsSpecialVehicle],
                        vpl.[Description], vp.[Amount], vpl.Id
                    ORDER BY v.[Id]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
            (
                SELECT
                    v.[Id],v.[Category],v.[Status],v.[Publication],v.[VIN], v.[EngineNumber],v.MMCode,
                    v.[Year],v.Kilometers,v.Fuel,v.Transmission,v.Colour,v.PrimaryColour,v.BodyType,v.[IsSpecialVehicle],
                    vpl.[Description] AS [PriceDescription], vp.[Amount], vpl.Id AS [PriceLevelId]
                FROM [Vehicle] v
                    INNER JOIN [VehiclePrice] vp ON vp.[VehicleId]=v.[Id]
                    INNER JOIN [VehiclePriceLevel] vpl ON vpl.Id=vp.VehiclePriceLevelId
                WHERE
                    v.[Status]=7 AND v.[Publication] >= 11 AND v.[Publication] <= 13 AND vp.[Approved]=1 AND vp.[VehiclePriceLevelId] IN (1,2,10)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX([Amount])
                FOR [Vehicle] IN (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: your  `@cols` query should just be selecting Id from Vehicle.. no reason to join those other tables and group by..   you're getting a column for every `VehiclePriceLevel` basically instead of  just every vehicle id.. once you fix this issue you should see a lot more errors

Answer (score 1):

This error because you tried to select number of columns that exceeds the maximum number of the columns allowed in one `SELECT` statement, see [**Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx):

> Maximum Columns per SELECT statement 4,096

The problem is here, the columns returned from the query:

```
SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(v.[Id]) 
                    FROM [Vehicle] v
                    INNER JOIN [Vehicle] ...
                    ...
```

Is larger than 4096, i.e, you have more than 4096 ids of vehicle. You can run this query and ensure that the returned columns are less than 4096.

You can also add `DISTINCT` to eliminate the duplicates (*it might be the problem*) `STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(v.[Id])` and remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY v.[Id],v.[Category],v.[Status],
   v.[Publication],v.[VIN], v.[EngineNumber],v.MMCode,
  v.[Year],v.Kilometers,v.Fuel,v.Transmission,
  v.Colour,v.PrimaryColour,v.BodyType,v.[IsSpecialVehicle], 
  vpl.[Description], vp.[Amount], vpl.Id
```

Comment: @Morgs - How many ids the query `SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(v.[Id]) 
                    FROM [Vehicle] v
                    INNER JOIN [Vehicle] ...` return? This is a limitation in SQL Server you can't overcome it

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't really include your schema, this is only a guess.. But I think you're looking for something this..  This would give you a column with `PriceDescription` and a column for every vehicle id.  Each row will have the `PriceDescription` and max amounts for each vehicle for that `PriceDescription`... Vehicle ID might not be very descriptive as a column header so you might want to change it.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(v.[Id]) 
                    FROM [Vehicle] v
                    WHERE v.[Status]=7 AND v.[Publication] >= 11 AND v.[Publication] <= 13
                    ORDER BY v.[Id]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = N'SELECT PriceDescription, ' + @cols + N' from 
            (
                SELECT
                    v.[Id] as Vehicle, vpl.[Description] AS [PriceDescription], vp.[Amount]
                FROM [Vehicle] v
                    INNER JOIN [VehiclePrice] vp ON vp.[VehicleId]=v.[Id]
                    INNER JOIN [VehiclePriceLevel] vpl ON vpl.Id=vp.VehiclePriceLevelId
                WHERE
                    v.[Status]=7 AND v.[Publication] >= 11 AND v.[Publication] <= 13 AND vp.[Approved]=1 AND vp.[VehiclePriceLevelId] IN (1,2,10)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX([Amount])
                FOR [Vehicle] IN (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```